# Reading a Text File From a .jar File

Tags: java, inputstream, embedded-resource, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I have a rookie question.

I'm currently writing a program that takes in alot of data from a text file using the File and Scanner class as shown below:

```
   File data = new File("champdata.txt");
   Scanner read = new Scanner(data);
   read.useDelimiter("%");
```

The Scanner then retrieves data from the text file correctly while in the IDE, but when I run the program as a .jar file, the file cannot be retrieved.

I've read a little about adding a text file to the .jar file itself, and using the InputStream and BufferedReader classes to read the file, but I have never used these classes, nor do I understand what they do differently/how to use them in place of the File and Scanner classes.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Are u placing the same file with jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Scanner` class has a constructor [`Scanner(InputStream)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.InputStream%29); so you can still use this class to read the data like you did before.

All you have to do is to read the file from the Jar, you can do this like so:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("champdata.txt");
Scanner read = new Scanner(is);
read.useDelimiter("%");
```

Where the file named `champdata.txt` is located at the root of your jar file (which is just a zip file, you can use any unzipper to verify where the file is being located).

Now if you want to have the same functionality while developing in your IDE, place the file in your source directory, so that when the project is being built, it is placed in your `classes` folder. This way, the file can be loaded as described above using `getResourceAsStream()`

Comment: This worked great, thanks alot for the help. Could you also explain to me in simple terms what the InputStream class does?

Comment: An input stream is something you can read data from, it is an abstraction that can wrap the data behind any file or url (webpage, any resource reachable via an url). InputStream is the base class and the JDK provides multiple sub classes of it like FileInputStream specifically for files, AudioInputStream for audio, ByteArrayInputStream for reading from a `byte[]`, and so on. Take a look at the doc here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html

Answer (score 3):

It will be necessary to retrieve the file by URL, since it is an embedded resource.  See the [embedded resource Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for more details.

### Update

> So if I placed the text file in a folder "Resource" in the src folder, the URL I'd use is "resources/champdata.txt"

No.  If it is in a `Resource` path in the Jar, the String needs to be:

```
..getResource("/Resource/champdata.txt");
```

If it is in the `resources` path:

```
..getResource("/resources/champdata.txt");
```

The string needs to be the exact letters, (**plurality** &) case.

Comment: But if I distribute the program to another computer, won't the URL point toward a directory on my computer and fail to work?

Comment: Not if you form the URL according to the instructions in that linked page.  Why not try it?

Comment: So if I placed the text file in a folder "Resource" in the src folder, the URL I'd use is "resources/champdata.txt"? Or am I missing something here...

Comment: The incorrect case & plurality was just an error on my part in the comment box, but I think that may have answered my question for now