# why isn't this try/catch method working?

Tags: java

```
FileExaminer(String filename) {
        System.out.println(filename);
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File(filename);
        System.out.println(file);
        Scanner input = null;

    try {
         input = new Scanner(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("fiel not found" + file);        
    }

    System.out.println(input);
    System.out.println(input.hasNext());

    while(input.hasNextLine()) {
        lines.add(input.nextLine());
    }

    calcluateCharCountAlpha();      
}
```

I'm having a strange problem. this is throwing a null pointer exception (also file not found exception). I assumed that for some reason the line setting input to equal file isn't working because of the `input = null` line. But if I remove the = null part 
ex:

```
Scanner input;
```

instead of

```
Scanner input = null;
```

it says that I need to "initialize" the variable.
if I delete the line entirely and change

```
try {
             input = new Scanner(file);
        } catch
```

to

```
try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        } catch
```

then the input can't be resolved

and if i delete the above and try to just do

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
```

where

```
Scanner input = null;
```

is. (not in the try/catch block) it says it needs a try/catch block.

so as far as I can tell. I can't declare input in the try/catch or its inaccessible outside of the try/catch.

If I declare it outside and assign it a value inside the try/catch without assigning it a value outside the try/catch then its not initialized

If I declare it outside and assign it a value outside and a give it a value inside the outside will supersede the value given inside the try/catch

If I only declare it and assign its value outside of a try/catch it says that it has to be in a try/catch.

so how is this supposed to work?(this is starting to get really frustrating)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This block has two paths through it:

```
try {
     input = new Scanner(file);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("file not found" + file);
}
```

One is the path when there is no exception, and the other one is when there is a `FileNotFoundException`.

The first path is fine: `input` gets a valid `Scanner` at the end of this path. The second path, however, leaves `input` unchanged, i.e. set to `null`.

To deal with this problem, remove `try`/`catch`, and let exception propagate out of the constructor. A very important rule of exception handling is that your code should not catch exceptions that it is not prepared to handle. In this case, your code cannot do anything about the missing file, because `fileName` comes from the outside. Therefore, throwing the exception is the right thing to do:

```
FileExaminer(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
    ...
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
    ...
}
```

Comment: now I have the try/catch working but its still having a file not found exception even though the file is there... its imported into the same package as the classes so it should be working...I can tell the variables are getting the correct values (with some strategically placed print statements) and thats what the file is called (even if case sensitive) its just not finding them even though it has the correct names.

Comment: @namenotfound "its imported into the same package as the classes so it should be working" No, it shouldn't. Importing a file in a package has absolutely nothing to do with accessing files at runtime. The only way to avoid a file not found exception is to make sure that the file is physically present at the absolute path from which you are reading it.

Comment: so how do I tell it where to find it other than giving it "whatever.txt"?

Comment: @namenotfound One way would be giving it `"c:\\some\\path\\whatever.txt"`. Another one is placing the file in the working directory of your Java program.

Comment: is that just whatever folder that the class is in? I would like this to work if   were someone else were to download it.

Comment: @namenotfound No, that's the folder from where your Java application is started. If you want to embed the file into the program itself (i.e. make the file a part of your program), put it into a resource, [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12961051/335858).

Comment: thanks :) its nice to get replies that isn't just "wow you're a noob just give up on life"  like I got on dream in code :)

Answer (score 1):

If you get a `FileNotFoundException`, you can't just catch it, print an error message, and proceed as if nothing happened. If that exception is thrown, it means your `input` variable is not initialized, and you can't use it.

It would make more sense to put all the code that uses `input` inside the try block:

```
try {
    input = new Scanner(file);
    System.out.println(input);
    System.out.println(input.hasNext());
    while(input.hasNextLine()) {
        lines.add(input.nextLine());
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("file not found" + file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Surround all the file operations part of your method with try catch to catch the error, and use `Exception` in catch block to catch all the exceptions.

Try this:

```
FileExaminer(String filename) {

    try {
        System.out.println(filename);
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File(filename);
        System.out.println(file);
        Scanner input = null;


         input = new Scanner(file);



    System.out.println(input);
    System.out.println(input.hasNext());

    while(input.hasNextLine()) {
    lines.add(input.nextLine());
    }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: "+ ex);

    }
    calcluateCharCountAlpha();      

}
```